# show images fit to desktop screen using simplegallary.js of image array list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in here my javascript function i want to show images from image array should show fit to the desktop screen size and tell me where to correct the code and please tell me if any other solution is there for this component

```
     var mygallery=new simpleGallery({
            wrapperid: "slideshow", //ID of main gallery container,
            dimensions: [960, 430], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of the images exactly
            imagearray: [
                        ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show16.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show15.jpg", "", ""],
                        ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show14.jpg", "", ""],
                        ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show01.jpg", "", ""],  
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show02.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show12.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show03.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show04.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show05.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show08.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show13.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show09.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show10.jpg", "", ""],
                ["http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show11.jpg", "", ""]
                ],
            autoplay: [true, 2500, 8], //[auto_play_boolean, delay_btw_slide_millisec, cycles_before_stopping_int]
            persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
            fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
            oninit:function(){ //event that fires when gallery has initialized/ ready to run
                //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance (ie: try this.navigate("play/pause"))
            },
            onslide:function(curslide, i){ //event that fires after each slide is shown
                //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance
                //curslide: returns DOM reference to current slide's DIV (ie: try alert(curslide.innerHTML)
                //i: integer reflecting current image within collection being shown (0=1st image, 1=2nd etc)
            }
                });



html code
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="http://www.sifasusa.com/Atimo_s/news/slide-show01.jpg">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: here the marquee component are used in many images are there but there size is fixed and they show as per small images for this i used simpleGallery.js file for that then i want show that images should be dynamic in fit to screen size e.g.http://www.gloster.com/ go to this i want this way to show image component

Comment: If you have a place, in this case gloster.com, where you seen the function you need, why not start out with grabbing that code, see what it does, how it works and how you can implement it into yours? If you then have issues/problems, ask a question here.

Comment: Henrik Ammer- but in my various website above code implement component just i want to use that existing one and improve that component.if any soultion is there then let me know...

Comment: Thats not "just", you are asking for a lot. There is need to edit simpleGallery and then add alot of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple Javascript to determine the screen size.

Here are the various function you can call to get information about screen size :

```
screen.width
screen.height
screen.availWidth
screen.availHeight
screen.colorDepth
screen.pixelDepth
```

So for you, all you should need to do is change the `dimensions` to

```
dimensions: [screen.height, screen.width]
```

And now your images should be displayed at those dimensions.